# Adding bootstrap-datepicker-rails to date_select in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

So, I have a form that uses 'date-select', which renders three select boxes per used date-select (year, month and day).

Instead I want to use datepicker, and I've followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails). However, I don't have a clue how to actually implement the datepicker in the form in the view.

I'm using the following line in application.js...

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
```

...so I guess I need to give the select boxes the class .datepicker?

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
    <div class="text_field">
        <%= f.label :title%>
        <%= f.text_field :title%>
    </div>
    <div class="text_field">
        <%= f.label :description%>
        <%= f.text_field :description%>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <%= f.label :start_date%>
        <%= date_select :start_date, :startdate %>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <%= f.label :end_date%>
        <%= date_select :end_date, :enddate%>
    </div>
    <div class="select">
        <%= f.label :title%>
    </div>
    <div class="submit">
        <%= f.submit "Spara" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Still nothing for date_field?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try :

```
<%= date_select :start_date, :startdate , :class => 'datepicker' %>
```

EDIT: I have replicated your code on my machine and found the possible mistakes:

This gem selects the date in a text field, not in a `date-select`  . The input should be `text_field` and it looks like this:

```
<%= f.text_field :date, :class => 'datepicker' %>
```

As described in the gem's install guide , you should be sure to `require` it both in your `application.css` and `application.js` . One more important thing : in your `projects.js.coffee` make sure that the DOM is loaded , like this :

```
jQuery ->
  $('.datepicker').datepicker()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried that now but nothing happens. Even more strange is that when I check the source code the class isn't even added to the select box. :/

Comment: Make sure all the `require` commands are there, and wrap your datepicker call with `$(function() { ... });`

Comment: Still nothing for date_field?