# how to use date picker in bootstrap form on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-form-helper

I use `rails-bootstrap-forms` gem to create a form in rail app. In the form, I have a date input:

`<%= f.date_select :end_date, hide_label: true %>`

I want to use date picker in `bootstrap-datepicker-rails` gem, it give a example that:

```
<input type="text" class='datepicker' >

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

or

```
<input type="text" data-provide='datepicker' >
```

I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712281/adding-bootstrap-datepicker-rails-to-date-select-in-form) and changed my code, but it didn't work:

```
<%= f.text_field :start_date, hide_label: true, class: 'datepicker' %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

Then, I followed the description in the bootstrap_form:

> If you want to add an additional css class or any other attribute to the form group div, you can use the wrapper: { class: 'additional-class', data: { foo: 'bar' } } option.

And changed my code into:

```
<%= f.text_field :start_date, hide_label: true, wrapper: {class: 'datepicker'} %>
```

It didn't work as well. So how to fix this problem? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your application js and css for required files

> Configuration
>
> Add this line to app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
>
> *= require bootstrap-datepicker
>
> Or if using bootstrap v3:
>
> *= require bootstrap-datepicker3
>
> Add this line to app/assets/javascripts/application.js
>
> //= require bootstrap-datepicker

this should work:

```
<%= f.text_field :start_date, hide_label: true, class: 'datepicker' %>
```

Comment: It's so strange, when I test now, it works...I have done everything you told before.  lol